# What is this monument in Tallinn called?

Tags: estonia, tallinn, identify-this

I'm looking for the name of a monument in Tallinn, Estonia. I visited it this summer and I think it is really interesting for tourists since it has some historical interest and it also looks nice. ;) I would like to recommend it to a friend that is in the region but I need to know the name.

It is located directly on the beach a little bit outside of the town. The monument was built to commemorate a war, but I'm not sure anymore if it is the World War II or the Estonian independence war. Directly next to the monument the Estonian dance festival takes place.

Comment: It can't be that interesting if you don't remember anything about what it looks like.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you mean the Maarjamäe War Monument on [Pirita Beach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pirita). This is a World War II memorial.

[image: Maarjamäe War memorial, photo by rudi-k, CC-BY-SA license]

Answer (score 4):

Are you talking about this one?

[image]

It's called [Russalka Memorial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russalka_Memorial).